# Memory Management issue? receiving "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, exc-bad-access

Having an issue with memory management i believe. i receive a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error when it tries to assign the second time (runs the code and makes the first assignment but the second time makes it die).

I have a function which will take an array of custom objects (contains a date and name variables). i need to sort this array into month specific arrays (all the aprils will go to aprilList, may into mayList, etc).

.h file

```
@class SceneData;

@interface DetailedSceneViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,   UITableViewDelegate> 
{
    UITableView *mainTableView;
    SceneData *sceneData;
    NSArray *monthsArray;
}


@end
```

.m file

```
#import "SceneData.h"


- (void) sortMonths {
Agri_ImaGIS_iPhoneAppDelegate *dataCenter = (Agri_ImaGIS_iPhoneAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSMutableArray *janList, *febList, *marList, *aprList, *mayList, *junList, *julList, *augList, *sepList, *octList, *novList, *decList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int count = [dataCenter.sortedDataList count];

NSLog(@"count: %d", count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    sceneData = [dataCenter.sortedDataList objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Jan" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"jan name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [janList addObject: sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Feb" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"feb name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [febList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Mar" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Mar name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [marList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Apr" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Apr name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [aprList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"May" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"May name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [mayList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Jun" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Jun name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [junList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Jul" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Jul name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [julList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Aug" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Aug name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [augList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Sep" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Sep name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [sepList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Oct" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Oct name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [octList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Nov" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Nov name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [novList addObject:sceneData];
    }
    else if ([sceneData.name rangeOfString:@"Dec" ].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"Dec name: %@", sceneData.name);
        [decList addObject:sceneData];
    }
}
}
```

am i handling the sceneData object incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing correctly your arrays:

```
NSMutableArray *janList, *febList, *marList, *aprList, *mayList, *junList, *julList, *augList, *sepList, *octList, *novList, *decList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

This syntax will only initialize the last pointer... You should use:

```
NSMutableArray *janList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *febList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
...
NSMutableArray *decList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

On another note, all those object are leaking, since (if I am not missing something in your code) they are local variables (not autoreleased) and you don't call release on them...

Comment: oh, haha! thats what i get for getting lazy. xcode didn't give me any errors or warnings so i thought init all of them like that would work. and you are right, they are all leaking, i hadn't gotten far enough to worry about that yet. thanks for the help!

Comment: @Log139 It is a good idea to implement the memory management from the get go. Adding the code later is an error-prone pain in the ass. Design, security and manual memory management is not something you tack on at the end.